# Attempt to encrypt plain text with RSA public key throws error "unable to load Public Key"

Tags: rsa, mac, openssl

I received an RSA public key from a colleague by way of a pem file:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEAwGbtPQW6k1S1N8GM4UDxwexV4M+5BHcjs/l397/Mjt/J9+yL4PMw
cdLTnO/PHwCne3DdWsxHoZA/MIHRF+K/d2yDJ8DWHIKtbbUx6/1NOoogauwx+Ush
hNsaT3BCCw+ruFiyPCNKE6JN98hdbiP/61Y9OPZw/9m3c0mMtDv0gtjLJ2Q1z308
DGDZOA3+fTo/PEAgoCycVl0WwwN+AFYsj4DRqIlnxbd0PTSqxVBV+T1oaNmN/8jl
E0zOyQNzOHhDFhJJMucodrUOIFmpWSX6Ff2sVaXY81z4oRq3KrVOK4LZkP6cpPdh
s4Qa6ztWuwJ1ZKK6jOZxF0U2015/4njvgQIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

But when I attempt to encrypt some simple text with it on my Mac

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey "/path/to/file/public.pem" -ssl -in "Some text to encrypt with public key" -out /path/to/EncryptedMessage.txt
```

OpenSSL throws exception

```
unable to load Public Key
```

Furthermore, key validation

```
openssl rsa -text -pubin < "/path/to/file/public.pem"
```

also throws exception

```
unable to load Public Key
3106:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64.50.7/src/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:648:Expecting: PUBLIC KEY
```

The public key was generated on a Mac and converted to pem

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -m 'PEM' -e > public.pem
```

The error message suggests that the public key is not in a valid format.  So what am I not understanding and how do I resolve errors?

**Edit**

```
hexdump -C -n64 public.pem
00000000  2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 42 45 47  49 4e 20 52 53 41 20 50  |-----BEGIN RSA P|
00000010  55 42 4c 49 43 20 4b 45  59 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 0a 4d  |UBLIC KEY-----.M|
00000020  49 49 42 43 67 4b 43 41  51 45 41 77 47 62 74 50  |IIBCgKCAQEAwGbtP|
00000030  51 57 36 6b 31 53 31 4e  38 47 4d 34 55 44 78 77  |QW6k1S1N8GM4UDxw|
00000040
```

Appears to be ASCII with no BOM.

Answer (score 4):

The `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----` header shows that this is a PKCS#1 file.  OpenSSL expects a PKCS#8 file which begins with `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` (note the lack of `RSA`).

You need to use the `-RSAPublicKey_in` option to `openssl rsa` to convert the file from PKCS#1 to PKCS#8 file:

```
openssl rsa -RSAPublicKey_in -pubin -in /path/to/file/public.pem -out /path/to/file/pkcs8.pem
```

Once you've done that, you can use your first command using the converted file.

A bit of Googling suggests that the version of OpenSSL on a Mac may not have the `-RSAPublicKey_in` option, in which case you may need to find a newer version, maybe on another OS.

Comment: If I remember correctly, before gaining that option, "openssl rsa" dealt _only_ in PKCS#1 format keys (with PKCS#8 only available via "openssl pkey"), so I'm not sure why those versions would have an issue.

Comment: @grawity+ in old OpenSSL most commandline operations used algorithm-specific 'traditional' formats for _privatekey_ files (PKCS1 for RSA, adhoc for DSA, SEC1 for EC) with only explicit `pkcs8` (and `pkcs12 -export`) commands using PKCS8; since 1.0.0 in 2010 generic operations like `req` and `pkey` use PKCS8 but `rsa` uses traditional. For **publickey** files however OpenSSL always used **X.509 SPKI** format for all algorithms until 1.0.0 when (only) `rsa` added the `-RSAPublicKey_{in,out}` options for PKCS1.